# BigQuery: split string with repetitive pattern to separate rows

Tags: regex, string, google-bigquery, split

I have a string with repetitive pattern like: `timestampField: <SOME_INT_VALUE> url: <SOME_STRING_VALUE>`. As you can see in the example, this pattern returns multiple (4 in this example) times.

```
SELECT my_string
FROM (SELECT 'timestampField: 1595351350 url: domainZ/aaaabbbbccccdddd timestampField: 1595351355 url: domainZ/eeeeffffgggghhhh timestampField: 1595351355 url: domainZ/iiiijjjjkkkkllll timestampField: 1595351356 url: domainZ/mmmmnnnnppppoooo' as my_string)
```

I want to break this big string into 4 (in this example) different rows, each row will have a string value

1. timestampField: 1595351350 url: domainZ/aaaabbbbccccdddd
2. timestampField: 1595351355 url: domainZ/eeeeffffgggghhhh
3. timestampField: 1595351355 url: domainZ/iiiijjjjkkkkllll
4. timestampField: 1595351356 url: domainZ/mmmmnnnnppppoooo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

one of simple ways is to use SPLIT as below

```
#standardSQL
SELECT 'timestampField:' || v AS part
FROM `project.dataset.table`,
UNNEST(SPLIT(my_string, 'timestampField:')) v
WHERE NOT v = ''
```

If to apply to sample data from your question - out put is

```
Row part     
1   timestampField: 1595351350 url: domainZ/aaaabbbbccccdddd     
2   timestampField: 1595351355 url: domainZ/eeeeffffgggghhhh     
3   timestampField: 1595351355 url: domainZ/iiiijjjjkkkkllll     
4   timestampField: 1595351356 url: domainZ/mmmmnnnnppppoooo
```

Another option using regexp with the same output

```
#standardSQL
SELECT part
FROM `project.dataset.table`,
UNNEST(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(my_string, r'timestampField: [^ ]* url: [^ ]*')) part
```

Comment: Both of them work, Thats amazing! Thanks. @Mikhail Berlyant Can you please explain the first solution - what does the `||` means in BigQuery?

Comment: it is [Concatenation operator](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/operators#concatenation_operator)